# Keeping lines in a file which are older than a certain date

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following file (you may recognize this as an ouput of `zfs list` listing all snapshots):

```
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_daily-2021-03-01-0525   Mon Mar  1  5:25 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2021-03-01-0552 Mon Mar  1  5:52 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_daily-2021-03-02-0525   Tue Mar  2  5:25 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-02-2117  Tue Mar  2 21:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-02-2217  Tue Mar  2 22:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-02-2317  Tue Mar  2 23:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0017  Wed Mar  3  0:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0117  Wed Mar  3  1:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0217  Wed Mar  3  2:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0317  Wed Mar  3  3:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0417  Wed Mar  3  4:17 2021
```

I would like to delete the snapshots (keep the lines) which are older than a certain day, e.g., everything older than March 3.

I know I can do something like:

```
ts=`...` # put in time stamp to compare here
for line in `zfs list -H -rt snap -o name,creation zpzetta`
do
  date=`echo $line | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'`
  secs=`date --date='$date' +'%s'`
  if [ "$secs" -lt $ts ]
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done
```

but this looks pretty dirty to me.

Is there not a more elegant way to do this? (as a shell script, no python, perl etc.)

Comment: [Why you shouldn't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)! Which shell is this, anyway? Bash?

Comment: It is bash. Thank you for the links, did not know these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a possibility, it doesn't compare dates, it takes advantage of the abbreviated name of the month and the number of the day and the year:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/Mar *[3-9].*2021\|Mar *[1-3][0-9].*2021$/p' foo.foo 
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0017  Wed Mar  3  0:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0117  Wed Mar  3  1:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0217  Wed Mar  3  2:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0317  Wed Mar  3  3:17 2021
zpzetta/sys/win2012@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2021-03-03-0417  Wed Mar  3  4:17 2021
```

If you need other parameters, just change the patterns. For example here it will retrieve the lines older than 04 november 2020:

```
sed -n '/Nov *[4-9].*2020\|Nov *[1-3][0-9].*2020$/p' foo.foo
```